# Understanding Refraction Formula In OpenGL Reference Pages

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

I'm puzzled about the formula from [here](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/refract.xhtml):

> For a given incident vector I, surface normal N and ratio of indices of refraction, eta, refract returns the refraction vector, R.
>
> R is calculated as:
>
> ```
> k = 1.0 - eta * eta * (1.0 - dot(N, I) * dot(N, I));
> if (k < 0.0)
>     R = genType(0.0);       // or genDType(0.0)
> else
>     R = eta * I - (eta * dot(N, I) + sqrt(k)) * N;
> ```
>
> The input parameters I and N should be normalized in order to achieve the desired result.

Could it be that the `+` before `sqrt(k)` should be a `-`?  For once, I put this formula in JavaScript and checked if it returns `I` when `eta` equals `1`, this was only the case with the `-` in place.  But also from a logical point of view, assuming $\theta_1$ is the entry angle and $\theta_2$ is the exit angle (as pictured [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Snells_law2.svg)), then we want to output $E:=\cos(\theta_2)N + \sin(\theta_2)N^*$ where by $N^*$ I denote the vector orthogonal to $N$ lying on the plane spanned by $N$ and $I$, facing the same direction as $I$.  In the formula above, $\sqrt{k}$ equals $\cos(\theta_2)$ so $\eta I - \eta \langle N, I\rangle N$ equals $\sin(\theta_2)N^*$.  Now I just need to add $\cos(\theta_2) N$ but in the original formula, I subtract that vector instead of adding it.  Where is my mistake?

Comment: It may be that there are some sneaky conventions at play. Your solution may be correct but correct for a different format / convention (I haven’t checked)

Comment: Hmm, the only room for conventions I can see is multiplication of incident vector and / or emergent vector by $-1$, but that wouldn't fix it.